# NSDate wrong output when add day to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);


// Retrieve NSDate instance from stringified date presentation
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// Create and initialize date component instance
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:2];

// Retrieve date with increased days count
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                   dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                   toDate:dateFromString options:0];

NSLog(@"Original date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
NSLog(@"New date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

**OutPut**

```
   2013-05-17
   Original date: 2013-05-17
    New date: 1412647-09-06
```

I add 2 day to that. The new date should be "2013-05-19?. Can anyone tell me what I wrong? Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `day` is correctly set to `2`? - And please post *code*, not *screen shots*.

Comment: Yep, as Matthias indicates, you never initialized your NSDateComponents date.  You need to use NSCalendar componentsFromDate to initialize things.

Comment: @HotLicks: Compare the first example (Listing 9) in [Performing Calendar Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html).

Comment: Thank you all answer. My problem is day. Now I already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you forgot to initialize the `day` variable. If you add

```
NSUInteger day = 2;
```

then your code produces the expected result in my test program.

Answer (score 1):

The `init` methode of `NSDateComponents` does not initializes the components. Thus, e.g., year is undefined. Form Apple's documentation:

```
An instance of NSDateComponents is not responsible for answering questions about a date beyond the 
information with which it was initialized. For example, if you initialize one with May 6, 2004,   
its weekday is NSUndefinedDateComponent
```

Comment: Have a look at [Performing Calendar Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html): You only have to set the components that you want to add. Therefore I don't think that this answers the question.